# Preventing circumvention of OpenDNS with iptables on a gateway server

Tags: iptables, opendns

I'm trying to setup iptables rules on my gateway server to force my kids to use opendns (I've recently discovered that 1 of them has manually is using google DNS instead on his local computer).

Here is my conf in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
```

It's working fine because when an IP is assigned to a local computer, the default DNS server is the 1st OpenDNS entry:

```
$ nslookup 
> serverfault.com
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
```

Now, if I put the following rules on my server:

```
#allow dns requests to opendns
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 208.67.220.220 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 208.67.222.222 -j ACCEPT

#block all other dns requests to other servers
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

...it's working fine, but only on the server itself, not on the clients. Indeed, clients are still able to use any other DNS servers than the ones from OpenDNS.

I suspect that as I'm performing NAT (gateway router), there is something wrong with the table I'm reaching in iptables.

Can you please help?
Many thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Sounds like this is just about `OUTPUT` vs `FORWARD`?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: thank you very much for your prompt feedback. It has solved my issue. I've replaced all `OUTPUT` statements by `FORWARD` as recommended and that worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: DNS uses both UDP and TCP.